# Having trouble creating a backup and restore of an AWS instance in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have a bitnami instance working fine on my AWS console. I want to make a backup of it so that if I mess something up I can simply deploy an older backup.

I followed the instructions here:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/backup-restore-server/

So I have the snapshot created. But how do I get a bitnami instance running based off of that snapshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page says:

> This feature creates a new snapshot of the disk, which can later be used to restore the server to an earlier state.

**To restore the snapshot**, you can use "Create Volume" to create a new Amazon EBS Volume from the snapshot. You could then restore the system to the state of the snapshot with these steps:

- Stop the instance
- Detach the current EBS volume
- Attach the new (restored) EBS volume with the same device identifier
- Start the instance

However, **if you wish to launch a totally new instance using the backup**, then the easier backup method would be:

- Use "Create Image" in the EC2 console to create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)
- Launch a new instance using that AMI

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had tried launching a new instance from the backup a couple of days ago but when I navigate to the resulting IP address (34.244.132.53) of the new instance it fails to load, giving a timeout error. 
So I was assuming it may have done something wrong creating the new instance.

Comment: I guess this is really a different questions so I'll mark it as answered and create a new question.